# Insert multiple rows from a select statement into an already existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a query that will pull data from a database table.  I am in the process of merging the results from my query into another database table and I need some advice.  My select statement looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.ActivePasscodes
WHERE ACCOUNT NOT IN 
('BCLions','DCL02','DEM02','DEMO2','Fission','Havilah','Mbac',
'NEW','OrkoSilver','PDAC2012','PDAC2012D','PROMO2','Rocktech','XMAS',
'Xmas1','Xmas2','Xmas3','Xmas4','Xmas5','Xmas6',
'Xmas7','Xmas8','CMP33','TEST','ZZZ3','DNB02','XXX02',
'DNBTEST','32576','TEST123','TEST REC','CCTest','XXX') 
AND Deleted <> '1'
AND CODE NOT IN ('21717312','24536779','27227816','37121896','47241',
'35965','51983','68696')
```

This query returns me 1501 records.  What I am trying to accomplish is to insert these 1501 records into another existing database table that has identical records (as in all of the columns match up).

Can someone show me or at least point me in the right direction as to how I can insert all the records returned by this query into my other database table?  I am fairly new to Microsoft SQL Server and have done some research on this but haven't found anything fairly similar to my scenario.  If something isn't quite clear please feel free to ask for further clarification.

I appreciate the help!

Thank you!

-Dave

Comment: is that database is on same server??

Comment: Yes it is located on the same server.

Comment: @MotoDate I Posted Answer try that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

You can Access Your Remote Table From Existing Database Like This:

```
select * from NewDataBase.dbo.NewTable
```

Same Way. Just You Need To Write `NewDatabase` Name and Specify All columns

```
Insert into NewDataBase.dbo.NewTable(Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4)
SELECT (Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4) FROM dbo.ActivePasscodes
WHERE ACCOUNT NOT IN 
('BCLions','DCL02','DEM02','DEMO2','Fission','Havilah','Mbac',
'NEW','OrkoSilver','PDAC2012','PDAC2012D','PROMO2','Rocktech','XMAS',
'Xmas1','Xmas2','Xmas3','Xmas4','Xmas5','Xmas6',
'Xmas7','Xmas8','CMP33','TEST','ZZZ3','DNB02','XXX02',
'DNBTEST','32576','TEST123','TEST REC','CCTest','XXX') 
AND Deleted <> '1'
AND CODE NOT IN ('21717312','24536779','27227816','37121896','47241',
'35965','51983','68696')
```

Comment: This seems to be working well.  Thank you very much!  At first I was getting the message: "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'table' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF".  It seems though that it runs fine when I set IDENTITY_INSERT to ON, run the query, then set IDENTITY_INSERT to OFF.  Do you happen to know why this occurs?  I am also getting a constraint error "The UPDATE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK_Account_Customer". The conflict occurred in database "table", table "dbo.table", column 'ACCOUNT'".  I should be able to figure this out though.

Comment: MY guess is that when I try to add a value from my query it then looks to another table to see if that value also exists in that table and if it doesn't I get a constraint confliction error.  I will have to look into this some more as I am new to this project and did not set up the database.  I greatly appreciate your help though!

Comment: 1) for `IDENTITY_INSERT` means you are inserting values in the column on which `Auto Increment` is defied sql server will automatically adds value to that column
2)`ACCOUNT` on this column while updating you are violating Constraint of that column for info `sp_heltext table_name` check for constraint here

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO MyTableName (MyField1, MyField2, etc)
SELECT MyField1, MyField2, etc 
FROM dbo.ActivePasscodes
WHERE ACCOUNT NOT IN 
  ('BCLions','DCL02','DEM02','DEMO2','Fission','Havilah','Mbac', 'NEW','OrkoSilver','PDAC2012','PDAC2012D','PROMO2','Rocktech','XMAS', 'Xmas1','Xmas2','Xmas3','Xmas4','Xmas5','Xmas6', 'Xmas7','Xmas8','CMP33','TEST','ZZZ3','DNB02','XXX02', 'DNBTEST','32576','TEST123','TEST REC','CCTest','XXX') 
  AND Deleted <> '1'
  AND CODE NOT IN ('21717312','24536779','27227816','37121896','47241', '35965','51983','68696')
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer this method seems to work well!